# Differences between getBytes("UTF-8") and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() of C#

Tags: java, c#, encoding, utf-8

I'm passing data between c# & Java, converting them in 4 stages:

1. to byte array
2. to string (simply adding each byte as character)
3. to `UTF8` bytes 
   4  to `base64` string

What I've found out that java conversion to UTF8 is different than c#.

I'll skip the `base64` conversion in the code below.

Java code:

```
// The result is [-26, 16, 0, 0]
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(4326).array();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length);
for (byte currByte : bytes) {
   sb.append((char) currByte);
}

// The result is [-17, -90, -66, 16, 0, 0]
byte[] utf8Bytes = sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

C# code

```
MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter objBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(objMemoryStream);
objBinaryWriter.Write(4326);

// The result [230, 16, 0, 0]
byte[] objByte = objMemoryStream.ToArray();
StringBuilder objSB = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte objCurrByte in objByte)
{
    objSB.Append((char)objCurrByte);
}
string strBytes = objSB.ToString();

objBinaryWriter.Close();
objBinaryWriter.Dispose();

// The result is [195, 166, 16, 0, 0]
var result = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBytes);
```

The two end arrays are different although the input arrays/strings are the same. (Java just using signed byte for displaying - but the values are the same)

I'm not allowed to change the c# code because it is already used by clients..

How can i adjust, and what is the problem in my java code?

Note: Java manage to read the result base64 string from c#, but then it is generating with the same data different string that c# cannot read properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `char` is unsigned but byte is signed. When you do `(char) -26` you are doing `(char) (-26 & 0xFFFF)` which what you intended was  `(char) (-26 & 0xFF)`

Try

```
for (byte currByte : bytes) {
   sb.append((char) (currByte & 0xFF)); // -26 => 230 not 65510
}
```

Comment: So simple :) I really ignored the signed/unsigned differences.. I just added 256 in my head, and thought every thing is the same.. Thanks allot

Comment: @RazizaO operations on `byte`, `char` and `short` are widened to `int`, first, which is easily missed if you use a cast.